# Fixing minor tape blemishes/bubbling after a fresh paint job

Tags: repair, drywall, patching-drywall, joints, spackling-paste

Unfortunately 1 week after a new paint job was done with a decent job of skimming and all, there was a small flood in a laundry room above.  Some water came down, but we averted disaster.  It's very minor.  You can see some small lines from some joint tape around 1 panel of sheetrock on 2 of 4 sides of that panel on the ceiling.  In another spot it looks a bit wet but I think that part will just dry and I can throw a bit of paint over it even if it discolors slightly.  It's just visible enough to be annoying.  The laundry room itself has a drain, but a bit of water pooled in a corner and a small amount made its way down.  It could have been a *LOT* worse without that drain.  Most of it just drained out, but the floor wasn't quite level.

OK enough background ... the tape has bubbled a tiny tiny bit and it kind of looks like an unfinished joint tape job.  Someone put mud in between the sheetrock panels, threw on some tape, and did a cruddy job throwing mud over it.

I ran a putty knife over the tape and flattened it out pretty well while it was damp.  Some tiny creases, but it's pretty flat.

OK so here's the question.  Should I remove the tape, or just throw a tiny bit of joint or spackle over it and paint or prime+paint?  Which is better?  Joint or spackle?  I'm thinking I can get away with a very thin skim of the dap pink stuff -- the joint compound OR the spackle (despite warnings), but maybe I just suck at DIY.

I've done decent patching with spackle for holes and whatnot.  The ominous warning NOT to use the spackle as joint compound confuses me.  I thought it might just be a bit harder to sand.

Comment: Can you add some photographs? It's difficult to try to imagine what your drywall looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the tape is badly torn up or loose, just sand high spots and then put one or two coats of drywall compound over it. I have no experience using DAP spackle as joint compound - mostly because I'm a professional and just use joint compound for joints. Spackle is more expensive when you're dealing with large quantities.

It would make a better job to go two coats - one feathered out eight inches each way and about 1/16" thick in the middle, and then the second coat feathered out 10-12 inches. But you could get away with one coat feathered out 10-12 inches, and flattened off at 1/16" thick for the middle 4 inches or so.